# Centering UILabel in UIScrollview using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How do I programmatically add `UIButton`'s to a horizontal `UIScrollView` using auto layout ? Now each time I swipe the scroll view, the button's should be at the center of the View.

Comment: There is not short answer for it..if button has to be in center always then it should not be on scroll view i guess

Comment: at least using auto layout how do i center the first button.?

Comment: if you want to keep the button fixed, keep it outside the scrollview

Comment: i need 'n' buttons to be added and scrollable horizontally. I need to add the first button the center of the screen... how do i do it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use on scrollview like this.why you don't try this process.
i hope help this.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRMZT.png
label should be center on scrollview.